# Update excel file with color

Tags: python, openpyxl

I have 50 excels that I need cells B7:AE15 to be highlighted the color yellow.
i defined the cellrange_1 = ["B7":"AE15"]
I then tried:

```
for cell in cellrange_1:
     worksheet[cell].fill = PatternFill("solid",fgColor="00FFCC99")
```

But that doesn't work.

Comment: I believe you should assign to `worksheet[cell].style.fill`. Also, don't forget to call `workbook.save`

Comment: Haha I remember that mistake from yesterday, thank you again. But I'm not understanding the change to make. I changed it to worksheet[cell].style.fill = PatternFill("solid",fgColor="00FFCC99") and I get the error: "Tuple object has no attribute style"

Comment: That cell range cannot work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to change the background and font color:

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill

for col_range in range(1, 51):
  for row_range in range(7, 16):
    cell_title = sheet.cell(col_range, row_range)
    cell_title.fill = PatternFill(fill_type="solid", start_color="#00FFCC99", end_color="#00FFCC99")
```

In case of any questions, you can make use of OpenPyXL docs: https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Answer (score -1):

Try this...

```
for cell in cellrange_1:
   worksheet[cell].style.fill = PatternFill("solid",fgColor="00FFCC99")
```

And below is an example for conditional formatting

```
from openpyxl.styles import PatternFill, colors
from openpyxl.styles.differential import DifferentialStyle
from openpyxl.formatting.rule import Rule

red_background = PatternFill(bgColor=colors.RED)
diff_style = DifferentialStyle(fill=red_background)
rule = Rule(type="expression", dxf=diff_style)
rule.formula = ["$H1<3"]
sheet.conditional_formatting.add("A1:O100", rule)
workbook.save("sample_conditional_formatting.xlsx")
```

Comment: Hi Hitesh, I just tried this and I get the error 'Tuple' object has no attribute 'style'; I feel like I'm going to have to update each cell individually for that color..